# How can I get rid of the outline/border on this input with TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm working on a To-do list project and I decided to try tailwindcss for the first time. It was great until I started working on the form for adding tasks. I looked around online and tried all of the solutions I could find but no luck.

What I have tried: `focus:border-none`, `focus:outline-none`, `border-transparent`, `focus:border-transparent`, `focus:ring-0`

Another issue I'm having is extending the inputs to fill the width of their container. In the chrome dev tools I simply added width: 100% and it worked. In the tailwind docs isn't that the same as `w-full`?

The form is created dynamically using javascript (see below).

The form:

[image: to-do project]

The code:

```js
import './style.css';
import Task from './create-task';

const addTaskBtn = document.querySelector('.add-task');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.task-list');

addTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', appendTaskForm);

function appendTaskForm() {
    addTaskBtn.removeEventListener('click', appendTaskForm);
    const newLi = document.createElement('li');

    const titleLabel = document.createElement('label');
    const titleInput = document.createElement('input');

    const detailsLabel = document.createElement('label');
    const detailsInput = document.createElement('input');

    const dateLabel = document.createElement('label');
    const dateInput = document.createElement('input');

    const deleteBtn = document.createElement('img');

    const taskForm = document.createElement('form');

    deleteBtn.src = './images/delete-icon.svg';

    const row1 = document.createElement('p');
    const row2 = document.createElement('p');
    const row3 = document.createElement('p');

    titleInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    titleInput.setAttribute('id', 'title');
    titleInput.setAttribute('placeholder', 'What do I need to do?');

    titleLabel.setAttribute('for', 'title');
    titleLabel.textContent = 'Title:';

    detailsInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    detailsInput.setAttribute('id', 'details');
    detailsInput.setAttribute(
        'placeholder',
        "e.g 'needs to be done before the guests arrive at 5pm'"
    );

    detailsLabel.setAttribute('for', 'details');
    detailsLabel.textContent = 'Details:';

    dateInput.setAttribute('type', 'date');
    dateInput.setAttribute('id', 'date');

    dateLabel.setAttribute('for', 'date');
    dateLabel.textContent = 'Due date:';

    titleInput.classList.add('bg-transparent', 'w-full', 'max-w-xs');
    detailsInput.classList.add('bg-transparent');
    dateInput.classList.add('bg-transparent', 'ml-5');

    row1.classList.add('flex');
    row2.classList.add('flex');
    row3.classList.add('flex');

    newLi.classList.add(
        'pl-4',
        'border',
        'rounded',
        'border-lightBlue',
        'align-middle',
        'py-2',
        'gap-2'
    );

    row1.appendChild(titleLabel);
    row1.appendChild(titleInput);
    row2.appendChild(detailsLabel);
    row2.appendChild(detailsInput);
    row3.appendChild(dateLabel);
    row3.appendChild(dateInput);

    taskForm.appendChild(row1);
    taskForm.appendChild(row2);
    taskForm.appendChild(row3);

    newLi.appendChild(taskForm);
    taskList.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out I didn't have tailwind configured properly! I needed to add a path to where my module was located in my tailwind.config.js file.

To all of you tailwind noobs out there, (in my case) I added `./src/*.js` to `content`.

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ['./dist/*.html', './src/*.js'],
    theme: {
        screens: {
            sm: '480px',
            md: '768px',
            lg: '976px',
            xl: '1440px',
        },
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                public: ["'Public Sans', sans-serif"],
                raj: ["'Rajdhani', sans-serif"],
            },
            colors: {
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

removing `'max-w-xs'` and adding `focus:outline-none` works well?

```js
const addTaskBtn = document.querySelector('.add-task');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.task-list');

addTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', appendTaskForm);

function appendTaskForm() {
    addTaskBtn.removeEventListener('click', appendTaskForm);
    const newLi = document.createElement('li');

    const titleLabel = document.createElement('label');
    const titleInput = document.createElement('input');

    const detailsLabel = document.createElement('label');
    const detailsInput = document.createElement('input');

    const dateLabel = document.createElement('label');
    const dateInput = document.createElement('input');

    const deleteBtn = document.createElement('img');

    const taskForm = document.createElement('form');

    deleteBtn.src = './images/delete-icon.svg';

    const row1 = document.createElement('p');
    const row2 = document.createElement('p');
    const row3 = document.createElement('p');

    titleInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    titleInput.setAttribute('id', 'title');
    titleInput.setAttribute('placeholder', 'What do I need to do?');

    titleLabel.setAttribute('for', 'title');
    titleLabel.textContent = 'Title:';

    detailsInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    detailsInput.setAttribute('id', 'details');
    detailsInput.setAttribute(
        'placeholder',
        "e.g 'needs to be done before the guests arrive at 5pm'"
    );

    detailsLabel.setAttribute('for', 'details');
    detailsLabel.textContent = 'Details:';

    dateInput.setAttribute('type', 'date');
    dateInput.setAttribute('id', 'date');

    dateLabel.setAttribute('for', 'date');
    dateLabel.textContent = 'Due date:';

    titleInput.classList.add('bg-transparent', 'w-full','focus:outline-none');
    detailsInput.classList.add('bg-transparent','w-full','focus:outline-none');
    dateInput.classList.add('bg-transparent', 'ml-5','focus:outline-none');

    row1.classList.add('flex');
    row2.classList.add('flex');
    row3.classList.add('flex');

    newLi.classList.add(
        'pl-4',
        'border',
        'rounded',
        'border-lightBlue',
        'align-middle',
        'py-2',
        'gap-2'
    );

    row1.appendChild(titleLabel);
    row1.appendChild(titleInput);
    row2.appendChild(detailsLabel);
    row2.appendChild(detailsInput);
    row3.appendChild(dateLabel);
    row3.appendChild(dateInput);

    taskForm.appendChild(row1);
    taskForm.appendChild(row2);
    taskForm.appendChild(row3);

    newLi.appendChild(taskForm);
    taskList.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="task-list h-40 "></ul>
<button class="add-task bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full">Add Todo</button>
```

Comment: I actually just came back on here to answer my own question haha. It turns out I needed to add a path to my src folder (where my module is) in my tailwind.config.js file. But thank you so much!